# Is it idiomatic Latin to paraphrase a condition using an imperative plus a future indicative?

Tags: idiom, syntax

In English, there's a common construction which consists of two coordinated clauses, the first with an imperative verb, the second with a future-tense verb:

> Take the first left and you'll find my house.

This is equivalent in meaning to a conditional:

> If you take the first left, you'll find my house.

Was this way of paraphrasing a condition also idiomatic in Latin? Are there examples of this construction in Latin authors? It seems plausible to me that one could say *Veni cras et me videbis* (meaning *Si cras venies, me videbis*), but I'd like to see some actual examples to be sure.

ETA: brianpck mentions a closely related construction, in which the coordination is with "or" rather than "and", and the equivalent condition has a negative protasis: "Apologize or you'll be sorry!" = "If you don't apologize, you'll be sorry!" I'd definitely also be interested in Latin examples of this (though for some reason I feel less sanguine about their existence).

Comment: Might be worth expanding this to include a related idiom: "Do X or you will Y" = "If you don't do X, you will Y"

Comment: @brianpck Interesting -- I've edited to include that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Torrego 2009](https://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110205626/9783110205626.443/9783110205626.443.xml) mentions this use in her paper on coordination.

[image]